# What is this schematic symbol? (Two small circles connecte by a bent line)

Tags: schematics, symbol

[image]

What does this symbol mean? It's part number is XM## and is connected in series with the output voltage of a chip.

Comment: I've only ever seen that used for a jumper. What does it physically look like?

Comment: On the layout file it is physically merged with the chip. I don't have the chip itself readily available unfortunately.

Comment: A colleague has confirmed that its a jumper, that can be removed to measure amperage/power.

Comment: @Drew you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 6):

This is a jumper. In this case, it is used to remove so that a power/amperage measurement can be made.